# Reading the result of an exe file in :vs in vim

Tags: vim

Many of my programs are console like applications, which take a data file, and print out the results, either on screen (more often) or in another file.

Since these days I'm doing some analysis which requires a lot of little tempting with one input data file, just to get a few numbers, I usually go: edit data file, start program, get result, edit data file, start program, get result ...

So I was wondering, is there a way in vim, while having open the input file, to define a function which would open a vertical split and load the result of program (pro12.exe) in it ?

How would one go about that ?

Comment: does pro12.exe support sending output to STDOUT? accepting data from STDIN? Or, does it require input, output file names in the command line?

Comment: Not sure about the first (STD...) - it is not a C program. It does not require any command line arguments. The input file name is hardcoded in, and all it does is write something out.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is probably write a Makefile to run the program (and redirect output to a file), and `:set` the `autoread` option on in Vim. Then, you can create a macro `r` by typing `qr:make<Enter>q` and run the macro with `@r`. The macro will cause Vim to invoke make, which will run the program to update the data file. The `autoread` option will make sure that vim refreshes the updated file without prompting you first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pro12.exe is in your %PATH%, this will invoke your helper app and vert-split-open a static output file name.  Map to whatever key you like.  QND: won't work when relative paths (bufnames) change via `cd`.  YMMV

```
fun! RunPro12()
    bufdo if bufname(bufnr($)) == '/path/to/pro12.exe.output' | close | endif
    silent exe '!pro12.exe'
    vs /path/to/pro12.exe.output
endfun
map <f3> :call RunPro12()<cr>
```

Comment: Not a bad approach. However, the vs splits just keep opening that way. Do you have any idea about closing all vs's (well just the opened one) on each function start ?

Comment: so to say, how would you go about closing the current vs on pressing any key (enter for example) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like `:bufdo` solutions as this command always messes up the current windows organisation.

In normal time, I'd use [`lh#buffer#jump()`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhVimLib) that jumps to the window where the named buffer is opened if it is already opened, or opens the window otherwise.

```
function! s:Run0()
  call lh#buffer#jump('/path/to/pro12.exe.output', 'vsp')
  silent exe '!ls'
endfunction
```

Given the requested *"to define a function which would open a vertical split"*, we could simply use:

```
function! s:Run1()
  let bn = bufnr('/path/to/pro12.exe.output')
  if bn >= 0
    exe 'bw '.bn
  endif
  silent exe '!pro12'
  vsp /path/to/pro12.exe.output
endfunction
nnoremap µ :call <sid>Run1()<cr>
```

Last thing. If as I suspect pro12 writes to stdout (the standard output, i.e. ~ the console), the last two lines of the function shall become:

```
vsp /path/to/pro12.exe.output
r!pro12
```

The "/path/to/pro12.exe.output" may be replaced with anything unique. Typically, I'd use a scratch buffer with a unique name having "pro12 result" in it.

PS: if in the function (this is important) you add a

```
nnoremap <buffer> q :bw<cr>
```

you'll be able to simply quit the output window simply by hitting `q`, from within the output window.